How to compile dart to js for a non-web target?
I want to compile dart to js for a non-web target (eg. fermyon/js or node)
How do I compile dart to js for a non-web target?
update:
I'm told it's possible and while I cannot find any specific documentation
it seems that there are 2 possible approaches:

webdev build --no-release suggested here
dart compile js --server-mode suggested here
with node_preamble (3rd party)

here is a base/example code using js and ts
also available in this example repo

set up node dependencies

npm init -y && \
npm install express && \
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node @types/express ts-node-dev


create the file tsconfig.json with the code below

{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "ES6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
  }  


create the file `src/greeting.js with the following code

export function greeting() {
    return "Hello from JS"
}


create the file src/index.ts with the code below

import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { greeting } from './greeting.js';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(greeting());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

how can I compile ad dart function to js
then import it and use it in index.ts
dart code example:
String greeting() => 'Hello from Dart';

notes

packages from node_interop's family seem to me that are "replacing" node rather than actually "interop"
dart issue

bounty
I'd greatly appreciate actual runnable code or detailed step implement it based on the purposely minimal code sample

I can fork your repo tomorrow and create a PR that demonstrates my answer.

Here's the PR: https://github.com/iapicca/dart_node_example/pull/3

Read below or just check out the PR against your example repo.
I'm not sure this is possible by only using dart compile js and the available options.
You can write a script to extract the function you want to convert to a JavaScript module from the dart build, however, but only if you wrap it in main() and call it. There may be an easier way using another tool from the Dart ecosystem, but a quick search did not reveal one.
Given greeting.dart
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('greeting')
String greeting() => 'Hello from Dart';

void main() {
  allowInterop(greeting);
}

Compile it without type guard checks (makes traversing the AST easier)
dart compile js --omit-implicit-checks -o src/greeting.js greeting.dart

Now, you have to write your script. It would look something like this:
import { readFile, writeFile } from "node:fs/promises";

import { parse } from "acorn";
import { simple } from "acorn-walk";
import MagicString from "magic-string";

const convertToJsModule = async () => {
  const contents = await readFile("./greeting.js");
  const ast = parse(contents.toString(), { ecmaVersion: 2023 });
  const magic = new MagicString(contents.toString());
  const found: string[] = [];

  simple(ast, {
    ObjectExpression(node) {
      node.properties.forEach((property) => {
        if (property.type === "Property") {
          if (
            property.key.type === "Identifier" &&
            property.key.name === "greeting"
          ) {
            found.push(magic.snip(property.start, property.end).toString());
          }
        }
      });
    },
  });

  if (found.length) {
    await writeFile("greeting.js", `export function ${found[0]}`);
  }
};

convertToJsModule();

This works because dart compile js without optimizations creates your function as a FunctionExpression property of an object. Something like this:
var A = {
  greeting() {
    return "Hello from Dart";
  },
  main() {
    A.greeting();
  },
}

Now greeting.js is a file with the following content:
export function greeting() {
  return "Hello from Dart";
}

And you can simply import it into src/index.ts as usual:
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { greeting } from './greeting.js';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(greeting());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

I created an npm package to help with this: dartscript. Using that you can setup scripts inside your package.json to help with the workflow:
  "build:dart": "dartscript --func greeting --out src/greeting.js greeting.dart",
  "prestart": "npm run build:dart",
  "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts"

Now simply run npm start and navigate to http://localhost:3000. You should see Hello from Dart.

This would probably be better if you only passed the dart filename and dartscript parsed the dart code to find the function name, compiled it, them converted to a js module from there.

did you just create a npm package tailored on my needs :O
you are freaking hero!

It needs lots of improvements. I need to learn more dart to make it more robust, but I was bored and I like developing tools. For instance, what if your dart function calls another function, or you want to support parameters without needing to build to certain values of them.

dartscript now supports functions with parameters and/or wrapping of other functions. You need to write your dart file using some features from the dart:js library, but seems like a fair tradeoff to be able to build a JS module from a dart function.

firstly setup your dart2js
$ pub global activate dart2js_info

no open cmd and create new project in dart
dart create dart_to_js

go to directory
cd dart_to_js

open your project by using this command or in any IDE
 code .

now in vs code or in your IDE open your project. you will see a lib folder in this you will get a main.dart file.
in main.dart you need to write your function which you want to use in js
for example
// lib/main.dart

String greeting() {
  return 'Hello from Dart';
}

void main() {
  print(greeting());
}
@JS()
library main;
import 'package:js/js.dart';
@JS('greeting')
external String greeting();

Import libraries or add annotations as you need.
dart compile js lib/main.dart -o build/main.dart.js

run this command and you will get complied build in build folder.
Now we will integrate this dart code in Js.
cd node_project
npm init -y
npm install express
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node @types/express ts-node-dev

your tsconfig.json will look like this
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

now create greetings.js or index.ts file in src folder.
  //you can also provide path from your pc to import after adding path in to packages file. or simply create a dart project inside your node project.
    const dartGreeting = require('../../dart_to_js/build/main.dart.js');

setup your server as you need.
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { greeting } from './greeting.js';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(greeting());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

npx ts-node-dev src/index.ts

run the project and your all good to go

so many things wrong with this answer: 1) no such a thing as dart2js_info; 2) the provided dart code doesn't even compile; 3) index.ts is unchanged from the code sample while greetings.js doesn't even contain "greeting" anymore. No offense, but this clearly doesn't work and smells like chatGPT

well it is was dummy project I got during an interview. dart2js_info or greeting they are just file names and project name you can change it. I think you have to give it a try by implement code after that may be we can see if it works or not if does not work just leave a comment I will reach you out to help you
